# semantic-ui, themes, how to prevent the body - font-family: Lato

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am trying to prevent `semantic-ui` to write the **css** rule, found in `semantic\src\definitions\globals\site.less`

```
body {
...
  font-family: @pageFont;
...
}
```

I try to add in `site.overrides` (`semantic\src\site\globals\site.overrides`)

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* to see if I make any change at all */
}
```

But I can see that this rule is **added**, but the previous one is **still there**. How can I tell `semantic-ui` to skip that specific rule?

**I don't want to change the `font-name`, I want to erase the rule, in combination to use a `@importGoogleFonts: false;` in `site.variables` to also prevent the font import